# c: something i don't understand

Tags: c

I have this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int i,j;
long int maxc=0,nn;

long int max(long int n)
{
    maxc=0;nn=n;i=1;

    if(n<10 && n>=0) 
        return n;

    while(nn!=0)
    {
        if(maxc<nn%10) 
        { 
            maxc=nn%10;
            j=i;
        }
        i++;
        nn/=10;
    }

    return maxc*(pow(10,i-2))+max(n/(pow(10,j))*(pow(10,j-1))+n%((int)pow(10,j-1)));
}

int main()
{
    long int n;
    printf("Dati n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%ld",max(n));
    return 0;
}
```

n= numer given by user
max=function that returns the maximum number consists of digits of n. E.G: for n=1234.max should return 4321,for n=26341 ,max should return 64321

The problem is that sometimes works compiler,i mean for some number it returns the value I expect,but sometimes not. usually return the same number of digits ,but replace (a) digit/s with 9 or 4... I can't get a rule to fix this problem.

Thank you ! I used codeblocks for ubuntu.

Comment: You should use `fscanf` not `scanf` (=

Comment: That looks terrible. Why not read input as string, then sort?

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from `pow`. It is a floating-point function that *approximate* the result. If it return a value slightly too small (say 2.9999 rather than 3.00000), your code will truncate it to the nearest lower value (2).

I would strongly suggest an integer or character solution.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the entire solution, but i will give you the idea.

- Scan the digits from the keyboard and store them in a long int variable.
- Covert the digits to characters in an array. (don't forget about ASCII code).
- Sort he array in descending order.
- Print the array taking care of the ASCII code ( in my example i stored values not chars that's why i can print them as %d ).

  ```
  /* Prototypes*/
  int stringConverter( char const * a, long int val );
  void decsort( int * const a, int digits);

  int main( void )
  {
      char a[ SIZE ];
      int digits;
      long int val;

      printf( "Enter the number: " );
      scanf( "%ld", &val );

      digits = stringConverter( a, val );
      decsort( a, digits );

          /* Printer */
          for( i = SIZE - digits - 1; i < SIZE; i++){
              printf( "%d", a[ i ] );
          }
          return 0;
  }


  int stringConverter( char * const a, long int val )
  {
      int i, int j = 0;

      for( i = ( SIZE - 1 ); i >= 0; i-- ){
          *( a + i ) = ( val % 10 );
          j++;
          val = val / 10;

          if( val < 10 ){
              i--;
              *( a + i ) = val;
              j++;
              break;
          }
      }
      return j;
  }



  void decsort( char * const a, int digits ){
  /* Any sort */
  }
  ```